# Error after updating Visual Studio to 16.10, Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: visual-studio

Since I have updated Visual Studio 2019 to v16.10, I got an error when I try to create new project (WPF App C#, but others such as "Console app'" are working fine), and also I cannot open my projects.

**Error is:**

> Project AAA could not be opened because the Visual C# 2019 language
> service could not be created. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
> from a call to a COM component.

**ActivityLog (Inside AppData) after I tried to open my project:**

> Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Protocol,
> Version=16.9.150.16657, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\liveshare.vscore\Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.VSCore.dll
>
> Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal, Version=16.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll
>
> SetSite failed for package [CSharpPackage]Source: '' Description:
> Package 'RoslynPackage' failed to load. System.ArgumentException:
> Package 'RoslynPackage' failed to load.at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(IVsTask pTask,
> UInt32 dwCount, IVsTask[] pParentTasks, Object& pResult)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.b__0(Task`1[] _)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.<GetCallbackForSingleParent>b__0(Task`1
> internalTask)at
> System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskAwaiter.GetResult()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.LanguageService.CSharpPackage.d__2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UIThreadReentrancyScope.WaitOnTaskCompleteInternal(Task
> task, CancellationToken cancel, Int32 ms)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass100_1.b__1()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.IgnoreObjectDisposedException(Action
> action)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass100_0.b__0()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass108_0.b__0()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog[T](Func`1
> function)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog(Action
> action)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean
> ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()
>
> SetSite failed for package [VisualBasicPackage]Source:
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal' Description: Error HRESULT
> E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error
> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException
> e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean
> ignoreUIThreadCheck)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()at
> Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskAwaiter.GetResult()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.<InitializeAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualBasic.VisualBasicPackage.VB$StateMachine_15_InitializeAsync.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UIThreadReentrancyScope.WaitOnTaskCompleteInternal(Task task, CancellationToken cancel, Int32 ms)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass100_1.<InternalGetResult>b__1()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.IgnoreObjectDisposedException(Action action)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InternalGetResult>b__0()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass108_0.<InvokeWithWaitDialog>b__0()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog[T](Func`1
> function)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog(Action
> action)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean
> ignoreUIThreadCheck)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()

[image: VS Error]

Tried many solutions, nothing works. Please help me! I'm frustrated.

(Tried to repair, reinstall, remove folders in Appdata (Roaming, Local..), open in safemode, reset settings, reload project, and more)

I have also tried what suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/394256/i-got-error-34the-39csharppackage39-package-did-no.html